# Using syntax/translations wiith locales

Tags: isabelle

Is there any known hack that allows custom syntax for definitions inside a given locale, using the syntax/translation mechanism?  All of my attempts at an "obvious" solution are generating type errors, which I am led to believe is caused by syntax/translation not yet being made "locale-aware".

Answer (score 1):

Raw AST transformations with `syntax` and `translations` cannot be used inside locales in Isabelle2016. There is a workaround for constants and types whose declaration does not depend on locale parameters. You merely have to issue the syntax declaration outside of the locale for the appropriate constant from background theory. Below is a proof of concept:

```
locale test = fixes a :: nat begin
definition foo :: "nat ⇒ nat" where "foo x = x"
end

syntax "_foo" :: "nat ⇒ bool" ("FOO")
translations "FOO" ↽ "CONST test.foo"

context test begin
term foo
```

This workaround does not work for constants which depend on parameters of the locale, because then constant in the background theory takes these parameters as additional arguments and the locale installs an abbreviation, which is folded before the custom syntax translation fires.

Comment: OK, thanks.  Unfortunately in my case the definition I'm hoping to provide a syntax transformation for has a type that does depend on the locale parameters.  I'll just have to forego any syntax for it.

Comment: Types cannot depend on locale parameters. So if it's just a matter of using the same type variables, the above workaround still works.

Comment: Sorry, yes, you are right.  What I meant to say is that the type of the definition in question depends on the locale's type variables, and the definition itself has a dependency on the locale's parameters.

Comment: Maybe `adhoc_overloading` (which however, still has some quirks, especially in combination with locales) could provide a solution (in future). (See the Isabelle reference manual, isar-ref.pdf, section 11.3 "Adhoc overloading of constants".)